# how to load applicationContext

Tags: spring, classpath, applicationcontext

I have 2 applicationContext file under the same directory and I want to load each time one of them. what is the command I need to use in order to run the application context from a command line? is there changes in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name of your `ApplicationContext` file in `main` method by `String[] args` parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to expand on user2550754's answer a little;  `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` can take an array of `String` locations of XML files (`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String...)`)  as such, if you wanted to use the following command;

`java MyApp [spring-context-file-1] [spring-context-file-2]`

you could use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args);
   //now your context is up and initialized
}
```

this would pass [spring-context-file-1], [spring-context-file-2] and any others in the arguments into the ApplicationContext